# jquery .post not triggering

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, .post

I can't seem to get jquery .post to actually trigger. Where is the glaring hole? The alert functions on click, but not the post. Doesn't show up in firebug console either...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#submitemail').click(function(){
               alert('this works');
               $.post("post.php","email=joe.blow@gmail.com&user=1");
     });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submitemail').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('this works');
            $.post("post.php", {email: "joe.blow@gmail.com", user: "1"});
        });
    });
</script>
```

The issue may be that the anchor is firing before the post javascript fires.

Comment: kalberer, great thanks that works! if you have a minute, what did we do and what does that mean? Ny anchor, did you mean <a href="#">.... #submitemail is actually a <span style="display: block;">

Comment: Yeah, I was under the impression that submitemail was an anchor tag.  e.preventDefault() stops the anchor from firing.  I would use an anchor tag instead of a span.  I am thinking the fix was that you were trying to use a query string instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Add a success function to check the post:

```
$.post("post.php", {email: "joe.blow@gmail.com", user: "1"}, function(data){
    alert("return data: " + data);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but the console was indicating that the post wasn't even firing... i could also tell beacuase i checked post.php logs which logs even if empty is posted.